# AJAX passes only the last element of array to MVC 5 controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to send two arrays of integer to my MVC controller via AJAX.
here is my JavaScript code:

```
    var condDeviceIDs = [];
    var resDeviceIDs = [];

    $("#selectDvcForCond").on('click', function () {
        var deviceID = $('#dvc-cond').val();
        condDeviceIDs.push(deviceID);
    });

    $("#selectDvcForRes").on('click', function () {
        var deviceID = $('#dvc-res').val();
        resDeviceIDs.push(deviceID);
    });

    $("#AddScenarioButton").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("AddScenario", "Device")",
            traditional: true,
            data: { 'conditionIDs': condDeviceIDs, 'resultIDs': resDeviceIDs },
        }
        );
    });
```

and here is my Action:

```
public ActionResult AddScenario(int[] conditionIDs,int[] resultIDs)
```

the problem is axaj passes only the last element of array to controller. I checked my JS code with firebug and it was correct.
for example the 'condDeviceIDs' contains [17, 4, 6], but when ajax sends it to controller, "conditionIDs" only contains [6].
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried  -  dataType: "json" ?

Comment: You need to add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. You may also need to use `JSON.Stringify`

Comment: @StephenMuecke to set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` make sense?, OP is able to post data on server

Comment: you are pushing values inside `condDeviceIDs` and `resDeviceIDs` but actually they are undefined instead use `conditionDeviceIDs` and `resultDeviceIDs` and use `JSON.Stringify` in order to send arrays to controller action.

Comment: @MICROCOM, can you show us posted values in firebug?

Comment: @MokshShah, I've seen issues on SO when you use `traditional: true;` and omit the content type (although not that it posts back just the last item)

Comment: @heiteshUpadhyay it didn't work...

Comment: Try using `JSON.Stringify`.

Comment: @Kartikeya how could I use JSON.Stringfy?

Comment: `data: { 'conditionIDs': JSON.Stringify(condDeviceIDs), 'resultIDs': JSON.Stringify(resDeviceIDs) }`

Comment: or `var data = { conditionIDs: condDeviceIDs, resultIDs: resDeviceIDs };` and `data: JSON.Stringify(data),`

Comment: @MokshShah you mean this? http://oi57.tinypic.com/o9mna9.jpg

Comment: @Kartikeya I tried both ways but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MICROCOM Im asking about this http://tinypic.com/r/2m7ah6o/8, I've tried same code you posted and I'm able to get all the values on controller

Comment: @MokshShah oh, it seems there is a problem: http://oi59.tinypic.com/jj309l.jpg I'm trying to figure it out. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MICROCOM, I couldn't see any problem except parameter name, your image says you're posting `conditionID and resultID` and in controller you're expecting `conditionIDs and resultIDs`, can you please verify this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
postData = { 'conditionIDs': condDeviceIDs, 'resultIDs': resDeviceIDs };

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    url: "@Url.Action("AddScenario", "Device")",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function (result) {
       console.log(result)
    },
    failure: function (result) {
       console.log(result)
    }
});
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddScenario(YourViewModel model)
{

}
```

Create ViewModel

```
public class YourViewModel
{
public int[] conditionIDs{ get; set; }
public int[] resultIDs{ get; set; }    
}
```